# Chrome Developer Tools window not appearing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I'm having an issue with getting Chrome's Developer Tools to work on my machine.

I've tried both Chrome Version 37.0.2026.0 canary and Version 35.0.1916.114 m and both have slightly different problems - I'm using Windows 8.1.

In the standard installation of Chrome, the Developer Tools options are greyed out. I've searched this everywhere and there is a Google post saying to enable it in your registry settings. When I go into my registry, there is nothing relating to Google in the path they've specified - [[http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DeveloperToolsDisabled][1]](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DeveloperToolsDisabled%5d%5b1%5d)

In the Canary version of Chrome, the Developer Tools options appear and are not greyed out or anything, but absolutely nothing appears when I click it (no window, no error, nothing).

Anyone have any ideas? I've tried restarting the machine, clearing my cache, reinstalling Chrome but no solution..

I'll keep looking for a solution and post it if I find anything!

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you disabled JavaScript in Chrome using `--disable-javascript`? This flag also disables the devtools, including the "Inspect Element" contextmenu option.

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhh! I went through my Chrome settings again and noticed that Javascript was being "enforced by my administrator"

I figured out what it was (so stupid): We use Google Apps where I work and it's been disabled in the Admin Console. You definitely pointed me in the right direction though!